# \ddot doesn't work with \mathbf using a template provided by a conference

Tags: math-mode, templates

```
%% LyX 2.3.6.2 created this file.  For more info, see http://www.lyx.org/.
%% Do not edit unless you really know what you are doing.
\documentclass[11pt,letterpaper,twocolumn,english, double-column]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{newtxmath}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\rmdefault}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\setlength{\parindent}{0cm}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{wasysym}
\usepackage[authoryear,numbers]{natbib}
\PassOptionsToPackage{normalem}{ulem}
\usepackage{ulem}
\usepackage[unicode=true]
 {hyperref}

\makeatletter

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% LyX specific LaTeX commands.
\special{papersize=\the\paperwidth,\the\paperheight}

%% Because html converters don't know tabularnewline
\providecommand{\tabularnewline}{\\}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% User specified LaTeX commands.

% It is advised to use the following option for Inputenc 

%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
 

\input glyphtounicode
\pdfgentounicode=1

%\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
%\usepackage{layout}


%\usepackage{bm}
%\usepackage[intlimits]{amsmath}
%\usepackage{amsfonts, amssymb, amsthm, amscd}
%\usepackage[all]{xy}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\usepackage{caption}
%\usepackage{rotating}
%\usepackage{psfig}
%\usepackage{color}
%\usepackage{ulem}
%\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{graphicx}
%\usepackage{amssymb}
%\usepackage{url,hyperref}
\usepackage{titlesec} 
%\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{ae,aecompl}

%\usepackage{natbib}
%\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
%\usepackage{times}

\usepackage{etoolbox} 
\usepackage{natbib} 
%\usepackage{hyperref,url} 
\usepackage{blindtext}  %only for dummy text, not for use in documents
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{float} 
\usepackage{subcaption}


\fancyhead{} % Clear all header fields
\fancyheadoffset[RO,LE]{-0.2cm}
\fancyhead[R]{\includegraphics[height=0.73in]{ARMAlogo.pdf}}%
\fancyfoot{} % Clear all footer fields
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
%

\pagestyle{empty}
%
\setlength{\hoffset}{-1in}
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{0.6in} % left boundary
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{0.6in} % left boundary
%
\setlength{\voffset}{-1in}
\setlength{\topmargin}{0.25in}
\setlength{\headsep}{0.25in}
\setlength{\headheight}{0in}
%
\setlength{\textwidth}{7.3in}
\setlength{\textheight}{9.75in}
\setlength{\marginparsep}{0.0in}
\setlength{\marginparwidth}{0.0in}
\setlength{\marginparpush}{0.0in}
\setlength{\footskip}{0.0in}
%\addtolength{\footskip}{2\baselineskip}
%
\setlength{\headwidth}{7in}
%
\setlength{\columnsep}{0.3in}
\setlength{\parskip}{6pt}


%
\newenvironment{copyrightfont}{\fontfamily{phv}\fontsize{8pt}{9.25pt}\selectfont }{\par}
\newenvironment{titlefont}{\fontfamily{ptm}\fontsize{18pt}{20pt}\selectfont }{\par}
\newenvironment{quatorzefont}{\fontfamily{ptm}\fontsize{14pt}{21pt}\selectfont }{\par}
\newenvironment{treizefont}{\fontfamily{ptm}\fontsize{13pt}{20pt}\selectfont }{\par}
\newenvironment{dixfont}{\fontfamily{ptm}\fontsize{10pt}{11.5pt}\selectfont }{\par}

\titleformat{\section}{\normalfont\fontsize{12pt}{6pt}}{\thesection.}{0.5em}{}
\titleformat{\subsection}{\normalfont\fontsize{12pt}{6pt}\itshape}{\thesubsection.}{0.5em}{}
\captionsetup[figure]{font=small}
\captionsetup[table]{font=small}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{ptm}
\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{ptm}

\titlespacing\section{0pt}{12pt plus 4pt minus 2pt}{0pt plus 2pt minus 2pt}
\titlespacing\subsection{0pt}{6pt plus 4pt minus 2pt}{-6pt plus 2pt minus 2pt}
\titlespacing\subsubsection{0pt}{6pt plus 4pt minus 2pt}{-6pt plus 2pt minus 2pt}

\renewcommand{\@listI}{%
\leftmargin=25pt
\rightmargin=0pt
\labelsep=5pt
\labelwidth=20pt
\itemindent=0pt
\listparindent=0pt
\topsep=3pt plus 2pt minus 4pt
\partopsep=3pt plus 1pt minus 1pt
\parsep=3pt plus 1pt
\itemsep=\parsep}


\titleformat{\section}
  {\normalfont\fontsize{12}{15}\uppercase}{\thesection}{1em}{}

\usepackage{caption} 
\captionsetup[table]{skip=0pt}
\usepackage[font=small]{caption}

\makeatother
```

I am using the overleaf template provided by the conference, but this only give me bold but no dot above the letter

```
$\bf \ddot{u},~\dot{u}, ~u$
$\mathbf{\ddot{u}}$
```

it works if

```
$\ddot{u}$
```

Comment: Maybe unrelated but never use `\bf` which is not strictly documented in LaTeX. Try `\mathbf` instead.

Comment: First of all remove `\usepackage{ae,aecomp}` (you should also trim down your preamble to the minimum needed). Next, `\bf` has been a deprecated command for almost 30 years. Can you please add a pointer to the template?

Comment: @egreg thanks, but what is adding a pointer?  here is the link to download it https://atlanta2023.armarocks.org/authors/#toggle-id-3  under templates

Comment: @Miraboreasu Yes, that's the needed pointer.

Comment: @egreg a clue, dot works if I only do $\ddot{u}$, it just doesn't work with mathbf

Comment: @Miraboreasu Also `\mathbf` has to go in math mode

Comment: @egreg sorry, but I still don't figure it out, still no dot when I use \mathbf

Comment: Whar egreg means is `$\mathbf{\ddot{u}}$`

Comment: @barbarabeeton thanks, but still no dot, only bold

Comment: Sorry, but the template is a horrible mess. Anyway, use `\ddot{\mathbf{u}}`.

Comment: @egreg wow, didn't notes that it works in this way, thanks!